# Add a new annotation to a member annotated itself with a specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I'd like to add an annotation to every member of a class, where the member itself is annotated with a specific annotation. I'll have to extend third-party code, to make it ready for Hibernate Second Level Cache - in this case, to add i.e. `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)` to the specific fields

I'm using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.9.1 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/1.9.9.1

```
public aspect EntityAspect {        
    declare @field : (@javax.persistence.OneToOne *) foo.bar.MyEntity : @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY);
}
```

The goal: Annotate every member of `foo.bar.MyEntity`, which has the `@OneToOne` annotation, additionally with `@Cache`.

The pattern seems to work, but AspectJ tells me

```
[java]      [iajc] warning at declare @field : (@javax.persistence.OneToMany *) foo.bar.MyEntity : @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY);
  [java]      [iajc]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [java]      [iajc] [..]\EntityAspect.aj:5:0::0 does not match because annotation @javax.persistence.OneToMany has @Target{ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD} [Xlint:unmatchedTargetKind]
```

Yes, the `@OneToMany` annotation has the `@Target` annotation - do I also have to declare that? And how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Interesting question. Next time, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like I did in my answer. It took me some time to recreate your situation with the information you provided. BTW, your aspect declares `OneToOne`, while your error message says that you are trying to declare `OneToMany`. That does not make things any easier either.

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax slightly wrong:

```java
declare @field :
  (@javax.persistence.OneToOne *) foo.bar.MyEntity : 
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY);
```

has a problem: The parenthesised `(@javax.persistence.OneToOne *)` means to target a return type that is annotated. You ought to omit the parentheses, then the annotation will apply to the field definition as such. Here is a reproducer in plain Java + AspectJ with faked annotations:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public enum CacheConcurrencyStrategy {
  NONE, NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, READ_ONLY, READ_WRITE, TRANSACTIONAL
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
public @interface Cache {
  CacheConcurrencyStrategy usage();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
public @interface OneToMany {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  @OneToMany
  int id;
  String name;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    System.out.println(
      Application.class
        .getDeclaredField("id")
        .getDeclaredAnnotation(Cache.class)
    );
  }
}
```

Running this without any aspects will print `null` on the console. Now add this aspect:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Cache;
import de.scrum_master.app.OneToMany;
import de.scrum_master.app.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import de.scrum_master.app.Application;

public aspect FieldAnnotationAspect {
  declare @field :
    @OneToMany * Application.* : @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY);
}
```

The console log now says:

```
@de.scrum_master.app.Cache(usage=READ_ONLY)
```

It works, q.e.d.